# How to make facebook like private message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When you send a private message to someone on FB in the TO field when typing the first letter a suggestion appears then it becomes a little box with the name of the user you selected which can be deleted, anyone got a tutorial on this?
thanks

Comment: [This looks like it'll do the trick.](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good tutorial – You'll need to brush up on some basic skills surrounding XML, PHP and AJAX... Definitely a good place to start though.

[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp)